# Text not wrapping in IE7 for Windows7

Tags: css, internet-explorer, windows-7, mobile, internet-explorer-7

I'm currently building a mobile site and while testing using Windows7 which uses IE7, I ran into a CSS bug whereby my position absoluted element doesn't wrap within a container (fluid width) and can't figure out why. Some input would be much valued.

Fiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/calebo/ScVYD/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without declaring a width on the heading, I can't see how it would wrap (although it is wrapping in Chrome). However if you take a different approach and use margins to position the heading, it can remain in normal flow and wrap naturally.

I made a [**demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/aJJJx/3/) that works for me in IE7, Chrome 14 and Firefox 7